# How do I know which is a function and which is an operator?

Tags: mysql, documentation, keyword

MySQL have both *functions* and *operators*. However, it is not that clear for an arbitrary keyword whether it is a function or an operator.

For example, I believe `ASCII()` is a function (it appears in the [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii) section of the manual). However, `LIKE` appears there as well, and it does not appear to be a function; for example, since the syntax does not force `(...)` after the `LIKE` keyword, and the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions.html) mention that

> By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and the parenthesis following it.

In some cases it is that clear. For example, the `IN` keyword appears in the [Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) section of the manual (a non-disclosing section name), and it appears there with the name `IN()` (as if it was a function), but the examples show `SELECT 2 IN (0,3,5,7);`, which hints that this is an operator (watch the space after the keyword).

In the same section there is `INTERVAL()`. Reading carefully shows the following line in the description of this keyword:

> It is required that `N1 < N2 < N3 < ... < Nn` for this function to work correctly.

which hints that this is indeed a function, and not an operator. `LEAST()`, which also appears there, does not mention whether it is a function or an operator.

---

My questions are as follows:

- Are there any internal differences between the concepts of *function* and of *operator* in MySQL?
- Is there a way to figure out, given a keyword, whether it is a function of an operator?
- Can a keyword be both, depending on context? I know that some keywords can both a function and a type, for example.

I wish to know that both in order to understand the abstract structure of MySQL, and in order to use it for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides a list of "non-typed" operators [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html).

Basically, a function is followed by a list of arguments enclosed in parentheses.  Even functions that don't take arguments, such as `now()` require the parentheses.

An operator, on the other hand, is part of the syntax of the MySQL query language.  These are known to the parser, which recognizes them.  Operators often use "infix" notation, where the operator appears between the arguments.  However, this is not required (just consider the unary minus operator).

A cursory look at the list of operators shows that something can be both an operator and a function.  An example is `mod()`.

The most important difference to me is that users can define functions.  But users cannot (yet) define operators.  Unlike object oriented languages, SQL does not offer a way to provide additional definitions for operators.

And, for your purpose, you should peruse the manual pages to get the lists of things that you care about.

Comment: Thanks; however, `IN` does not appear in the page you've linked, and as I wrote, it seems to be an operator. Any specific guess regarding that keyword?

Comment: @Bach . . . It does appear on one of the more specific lists (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html).  But then that list is for both operators and functions, leading to the conclusion that it is a function -- which `in` is not.